# how to pass javascript variable to url in smarty

Tags: php, javascript, smarty

I am new in smarty and i want to know something like...

i have javasript code in .tpl file

```
var dispDate = myJsDate.getDate()+'/'+ (myJsDate.getMonth()+1) + '/' + myJsDate.getFullYear();
above code return : 08/12/2012
```

and have html code in that .tpl file

```
<a href="eventPost.php">Create A New Event</a>
<a href="commitment.php">Create A New Commitment.</a>
<a href="areaPost.php">Create A New Visiting Area.</a>
```

my query is
i want to pass that javascript variable "dispDate" in url

like
Code:

```
eventPost.php?ed=08/12/2012
commitment.php?ed=08/12/2012
areaPost.php?ed=08/12/2012
```

Comment: Is necessary to send the date from javascript? PHP could not calculate the date internally?

Comment: yah because i have used calendar so it is necessary to send the date from javascript. when someone clicked on date box it shows the date of the box and i want to pass that date to other page

Comment: Then you can create a form and send the date by post method. You can use jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using jQuery:

```
$("#eventPost").click(function() {
  var dispDate = myJsDate.getDate()+'/'+ (myJsDate.getMonth()+1) + '/' + myJsDate.getFullYear();
  $.get("eventPost.php", { date: dispDate} );
});

<a href="#" id="eventPost">Create A New Event</a>
```

It is not the complete answer but you can serve to start.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Scond option, without jquery would be: simply not use href attribute, but onclick.

Then you would have for example:

```
  <a href="areapost.php"
     onclick="location.href='areapost.php?ed=' + dispDate; return false;">
     .... 
  </a>
```